# Unit test for public method that returns pointer to a private member

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have such code:

```
class Foo
{
private :

    int m_nValue;

public :

    explicit Foo(const int nValue) : 
        m_nValue(nValue)
    {
    }

    const int* Pointer() const
    {
        return &m_nValue;
    }
};

void Test()
{
    Foo obj(3);

    // I want to do something like this.
    //Assert::AreEqual(&obj.m_nValue, obj.Pointer());
}
```

I want to test `Pointer()` method that returns an address of the private field `m_nValue`. Can someone please help with some nice solution for this situation. I can make testing class/function a friend but I really don't like it.

Maybe it's not the method that should be tested. But as far as I know all public method should be tested.

Tests are written in C++ for C++ code in MSVS 2012

Comment: You could call `Pointer()` twice and compare the results. That just about covers all the (defined) behavior you can get from this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be testing the internals of the class just its observable behavior. The test should be

```
Asser::AreEqual( *obj.Pointer(), 3 );
```

Comment: I guess this is the best way for my situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I always advise to not test trivial behavior. I would classify this as trivial. In the Java world this is akin (not exactly but close) to testing a getter which Martin from Clean Code advises against.

The best you could do is test that the pointer is not null and that its dereferenced value is what you expect.